# Unable to call views

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using Sails and when I attempt to call the login action of my UsersController the view response is not getting loaded. I know my routing is working, because the console.log successfully logs both the loginpassword and loginname. However, the res.view() doesn't work. Neither does returning res.view().

```
module.exports = {

create: function(req, res) {    },
destroy: function(req, res) {
},

login: function(req, res) { var loginname = req.param("loginname");
var loginpassword = req.param("loginpassword");
console.log(loginname + ' ' + loginpassword);

res.view();
},

logout: function(req, res) {
},

_config: {}
};
```

I have a /views/user/login.ejs and all it currently contains is a header block with some test text, but I can't get that to render at all. Any thoughts?

Edit:
I've noticed that when I look at my Chrome developer tools and I view the Response portion of the Network tab, I've actually getting my view loaded back into the layout <%-body%> but the page itself is not loading the returned view. Is this a bug or am I doing something stupid? I'm on the latest stable.

Here's the code: https://github.com/FreefallGeek/SailtsTest

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are using a jquery.post which is a ajax request and you simply don't render the response.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You might want to use a form and optionaly submit the form by js/jquery.

Alternatively you need to render just partial html in the success function of jquery.post